# In PHP how do I take a base64 encoded png and output that png as an image?

Tags: php, png, base64

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get image from base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571132/get-image-from-base64-string)

I tried

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo base64_decode($data);`
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: a base64 encoded png. It works fine when I put `$data` in a data URI

Comment: For example, Firefox says something like "The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors"

Comment: Don't forget different browsers have different size limit, the only way to be sure it works is if the base64 is 32k or less (I don't mean the .PNG image, I mean the base64 output).

Comment: I assume the extra backtick(`) in your code after the base64_decode(); is a typo?

Comment: if you redirect `echo base64_decode($data);` to a file (image.png) can you open it all right? what is its size (both in bytes and in pixels)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for trying to help. The problem was I was that I forgot to url encode the query parameter before I sent it to the PHP script.

Answer (score 3):

A png data url looks like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,[actual data]
```

You have to cut the beginning to be able to `base64_decode` it.
Also, if you remove the `header` call, you will be able to see any error message your code outputs.

Comment: Thank you. I am cutting the beginning, and it is still not working. :(

Comment: What is the error message? And I don't mean the "The image cannot be..." one.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has this magical function named [imagecreatefromstring()](http://lv.php.net/imagecreatefromstring) too...
But there is no need to use it if you need to show image only.