# get image from base64 string

Tags: php

I am trying to take a base64 encoded string and return it as an image in php using `$_POST`. On line one if I use `$_POST['imgdata']` it returns error from the `preg_match` if i were hard code the base64 string  instead of using `$_POST` it all works and returns the image. how can i make this work by using the `$_POST`

works

```
$imgstr = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
```

does not work

```
$imgstr = $_POST['imgdata'];
```

full code

```
$imgstr = $_POST['imgdata'];   
// Grab the MIME type and the data with a regex for convenience
if (!preg_match('/data:([^;]*);base64,(.*)/', $imgstr, $matches)) {
    die("error");
}

// Decode the data
$content = base64_decode($matches[2]);

// Output the correct HTTP headers (may add more if you require them)
header('Content-Type: '.$matches[1]);
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($content));

// Output the actual image data
echo $content;
```

Comment: The POSTed value looks like...?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams i added the full string

Comment: have you tried to echo $_POST['imgdata'] and compare?

Comment: @haynar if i echo $_POST it returns blank page and var_dump returns null

Comment: so the problem is at client side, when sending the data, can you show us the client side code?

Comment: @haynar i havent created any client side code yet i'm doing it from the browser url like this `http://mywebsite.com/dataurl_decode.php?imgdata=data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG‌​goAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAAAoCAYAAAC7HLUcAAADr0lEQVR4Xu2brZIqMRCFsy8A`

Comment: ah that's why it is null, you are sending the data as GET, but trying to get it as POST, use $_GET instead

Comment: @haynar i tried both get and post and still get null. by the way i get error "Notice: Undefined index: imgdata"

Comment: it is better to implement the client-side scripts, because the data which you can send via GET is limited and in case of base64-encoded images I guess the length of data will exceed that limit, so at first make a simple implementation at client-side with a POST data

Comment: Might want to try `$_REQUEST`.

Answer (score 17):

As was noted the "+" should not be missed, the rest is straight forward.  Use $_REQUEST if you are not sure is it post or get.

```
// requires php5
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'images/');
$img = $_REQUEST['img'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
```

Comment: Don't you also have to replace that + signs? In iOS that would be encodedString = [encodedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];

Answer (score 7):

This is the One., Would you like the following i think.,

```
<?php
$imgstr = 'image/png;base64,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';
$new_data=explode(";",$imgstr);
$type=$new_data[0];
$data=explode(",",$new_data[1]);
header("Content-type:".$type);
echo base64_decode($data[1]);
?>
```

The above code will generates the output as per your wish.,Try this..This may help you.

Sorry For The Delay Reply.,Now Only I Recover My StackOverFlow Account After a long time.

**Note :** Ignore the empty space's in before the starting '' tag on the PHP file you are using for image decode.,If any empty is on that file means it throws Error message and it doesn't create or show the original image after the decodes.

Comment: i am trying to use the $_POST variable to send the string to a php page

Comment: Just add the hidden field and place the value to get in POST Variable.,like <input type="hidden" name="imgstr" value="image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode('photo.png');?>"> and get the value in post while form submitting $_POST['imgstr'] also assign it to $imgstr=$_POST['imgstr'];

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABl'
       . 'BMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDr'
       . 'EX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r'
       . '8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
$data = base64_decode($data);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
if ($im !== false) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
else {
    echo 'An error occurred.';
}
?>
```

source: documentation.

check out [imagecreatefromstring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why the regex isn't working for you, I copied the base64 post data and your code and it worked fine.  You can try this instead which doesn't use regex and may be a little faster and use less memory.

```
$imgstr = $_GET['imgdata'];

list($type, $imgstr) = explode(';', $imgstr);
list(, $type)        = explode(':', $type);
list(, $imgstr)      = explode(',', $imgstr);
$content = base64_decode($imgstr);
```

Comment: it doesnt work. if i try to put this in my browser `http://mywebsite.com/dataurl_decode.php?imgdata=data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAAAoCAYAAAC7HLUcAAADr0lEQVR4Xu2brZIqMRCFsy8A` just returns a blank page

Comment: A blank page may indicate a parse error and you have `display_errors` set to off.  By the way, that is `$_GET` data, not `$_POST`, so that's probably why the regex isn't working for you.

Comment: Probably because `$_POST['imgdata']` is not set.  If you are passing the data in the URL query string, you need to use `$_GET['imgdata']` instead.

Comment: Also the image is breaking because the `+` in the base64 data is getting converted to a `' '` because URLs treat the `+` as a space.  You shouldn't pass that via get, instead use post or call `urlencode` on the data before you put it in the query string.

Comment: Or just do a `str_replace(' ', '+', ...);`

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code it is working fine for me,

```
$data = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
$data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $data);
$data = str_replace(' ', '+', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data); // Decode image using base64_decode
$file = uniqid() . '.png'; //Now you can put this image data to your desired file using file_put_contents function like below:
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capture parts by this regex :

^data:([a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z]+);base64\,([a-zA-Z0-9+\=/]+)$

Answer (score 0):

```
$imgstr = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
preg_match("/data\:image\/(.*)\;base64/",$imgstr, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

^^^^ Return file extension.

```
$data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $imgstr);
data = str_replace(' ', '+', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);
file_put_contents("/files/youfilemane.".$match[1],$data);
```

^^^^ Create file from base64.

Comment: Colons and semicolons do not require escaping in a regex pattern. The pattern to extract the extension can be as simple as `~data:image/\K[^;]+~` then just use the `[0]` match