# passing canvas image to php

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

I'm going to upload the canvas image into MYSQL. By using php, but before that, how can I pass the canvasData to php. I've done some searching, but some of the solution are complicated for me. That's why I decide to post a question on here. I'm doing in a localhost environment.

There is a `capture` button when click on it, will activate this function. It will capture the canvas photo.

```
function()
{       context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 300, 200);
        var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}
```

as I know right now the canvasData variable will be base64 code.

What is the best solution for me to pass this data to php for me to upload to my database.
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

js side:

```
context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 300, 200);
var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', url, true);

xhr.onload = function() {
    alert('hooray! uploaded.');
}
xhr.send(canvasData);
```

php side example you can take here [get image from base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571132/get-image-from-base64-string)

Comment: May I ask you some question, how `canvasData` variable pass into the url?

Comment: I know how it works already after I watch this [AJAX Tutorial](http://youtu.be/woNQ2MA_0XU)

Comment: is it a must to use javascript, possible just html to php? not using ajax or js?